# What happens to a Core Data object when it's deleted and still have references to it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

What happens to a Core Data object if it still has references to it, but is deleted? How should you handle this situation?

Comment: on core data you have on delete rules, you can do nothing, nullify, delete on cascade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you tell your managed object context to delete an object:

```
[aContext deleteObject:aManagedObject];
```

nothing actually happens to the object until `[aContext save:&error];` is next sent.

In the meantime, you can check the `isDeleted` property of the object.

You can also check whether the object's `managedObjectContext` is`nil`, indicating the object has been deleted.